# Why is there no unanswered questions tab for Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I would like to be able to view unanswered questions on Stack Exchange rather than hopping around between the different sites I am a member of.

Is there a reason that functionality is not there?

Alternatively / Maybe better would be a Stack Exchange tab that was, unanswered on sites I am a member of, as the list grows I am sure filtering it down would probably be needed.

Comment: We aggregate the network, on some sites like SO questions are answered *very* rapidly...the page would be invalid almost as soon as it was rendered (since that aggregation also has a delay).  There may be other reasons, but that's a pretty big technical/usefulness blocker in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already sort-of do that: On [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), make a filter that contains the sites you're interested in, navigate to that filter with the `tagged questions` button, and select the `no answers` tab.

This is different from the `unanswered` tab on the individual sites, which list all questions with no upvoted answer. Maybe your feature request is to add an `unanswered` tab next to the `no answers` tab?

(Apologies if you knew this already, it wasn't clear from your question.)

Comment: I actually didn't, that is close enough for me. Thanks.